# What is $q^{\frac{1}{2}h \otimes h}$?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups

One can find in some sources (e.g. Pavel Etingof, Lectures on representation theory and KZ equation, page 91) formula for $R$ matrix (for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ case)

$$R = q^{\frac{1}{2} h \otimes h} \sum_{n \geq 0} q^{ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} }  \frac{(q-q^{-1})^n e^n \otimes f^n}{[n]!} $$

**Question.** What is $q^{\frac{1}{2}h \otimes h}$ ?

**Remark.** There is no such thing as $h$ for $U_q ( \mathfrak{sl}_2 )$. There is just $q^h$ (some authors denote it as $K$). Of course you may say that that $K$ is diagonalizable, so there is no problem to find logarithm. I would reply, that logarithm is not defined uniquely. At least, if $q = e^{\hbar}$, then you may replace $h \rightarrow h + \frac{2 \pi i}{\hbar}$. It is important
$$e^{\frac{1}{2} \hbar h \otimes h} \neq e^{\frac{1}{2} \hbar (h + \frac{2 \pi i}{\hbar}) \otimes h}$$

You see, it is well defined for representations of even highest weight. It is defined up to sign for representations with odd highest weight. And it is not well defined for Verma module of generic highest weight.

Comment: My guess is that you understand $q^{\frac{1}{2}h\otimes h}$ as an operator. It acts on the tensor product of weight vectors $v_\lambda\otimes v_\mu$ by $q^{\lambda(h)\mu(h)/2}$.

Comment: Of course. The point is that $q^{ \frac{ \lambda \mu}{2} }$, $q^{\lambda}$,  $q^{ \mu}$ are not well defined. So you should make a choice. The result depends on these choices (and this is more than just up to global constant).

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you mean when you write  $h+2\pi i/\hbar$.

Comment: @David Hill Do you know what is quantum group $U_q( \mathfrak{sl}_2 )$?

Comment: Umm. Yeah, I have some experience. You are claiming that two things should be equal, but I don't think you've thought it through. Why don't you write down a couple of power series.

Comment: Did I claim this? I implicitly claimed that $q^{h} = q^{h + \frac{2 \pi i}{\hbar} }$. So $h$ is not well defined.

Comment: Well defined element of *what*? Let me come back to my question: what do you think you mean when you write $h+2\pi i/\hbar$? The element $h$ most certainly **is** a well defined element of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. You do know what $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is, right?

Comment: I do know what $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is. But we do not considering representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. We are considering representations of $U_q ( \mathfrak{sl}_2 )$. And $h$ is not an element of $U_q ( \mathfrak{sl}_2 )$, but $q^h \in U_q ( \mathfrak{sl}_2 )$.

Comment: @quinque How about $K^{1/2} \otimes K^{1/2}$. K is grouplike and $\Delta(K) =  K \otimes K$. From standard Lie algebra, this would normally involve commutators, but in this case, you have $[h,h] = 0$.

Comment: @G. Bergeron I do not understand your phrase "normally involve commutators". 

But the element (wich you suggested) is not what I am looking for.

Consider an element $v_1 \otimes v_2 \in V_1 \otimes V_2$. Let $K v_1 = q^{n_1}$ and $K v_2 = q^{n_2} v_2$. Then $K^{\frac{1}{2}} \otimes K^{ \frac{1}{2} } (v_1 \otimes v_2) = q^{\frac{1}{2}(n_1 + n_2)} v_1 \otimes v_2$. But $q^{\frac{1}{2} h \otimes h} (v_1 \otimes v_2) = q^{ \frac{1}{2} n_1 n_2} v_1 \otimes v_2$.